# Not work form when use in bootstrap in php

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Programming hence need some help.I am use bootstrap and ajax for create from and progress bar for upload file to server but form is not work when click button.
when i am click buttom nothing happens.I am change button to input type="sumbit" but did not work again

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php
    require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();
    ?>


      <html lang="fa" dir="rtl">

       <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="assets/img/apple-icon.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.png">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>

        <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <title>
            پنل مدیریت
        </title>
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no'name='viewport'/>
        <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
              href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Roboto+Slab:400,700|Material+Icons"
        />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <!-- Markazi Text font include just for persian demo purpose, don't include it in your project -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cairo&amp;subset=arabic" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- CSS Files -->
        <link href="assets/css/material-dashboard.css?v=2.1.0" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="assets/css/material-dashboard-rtl.css?v=1.1" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <!-- CSS Just for demo purpose, don't include it in your project -->
        <link href="assets/demo/demo.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <!-- Style Just for persian demo purpose, don't include it in your project -->
        <style>
            body,
            h1,
            h2,
            h3,
            h4,
            h5,
            h6,
            .h1,
            .h2,
            .h3,
            .h4 {
                font-family: "Cairo";
            }
        </style>
        </head>

        <body class="">
        <div class="wrapper ">
        <div class="sidebar" data-color="purple" data-background-color="white" data-image="assets/img/sidebar-1.jpg">

            <div class="logo">
                <a href="http://www.creative-tim.com" class="simple-text logo-normal">
                    مدیریت محتوا
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="nav">

                    <li class="nav-item  ">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./category.php">
                            <i class="material-icons">bubble_chart</i>
                            <p>دسته بندی</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item ">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./map.html">
                            <i class="material-icons">location_ons</i>
                            <p>نقشه</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-panel">
        <!-- Navbar -->



    <div class="content">

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <form  id="uploadForm" action="uploadajax.php"  method="post">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="bmd-label-floating">عنوان را بنویسید</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title_video" required>

                        </div>
                        </div>


                        </div>
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label>توضیحات فیلم</label>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="bmd-label-floating">توضیحات در مورد فیلم را در این کادر</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="content_video"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="custom-file">
                                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="userImage" id="userImage"
                                       required>
                                <label class="custom-file-label border-primary" for="inputGroupFile04">فیلم را
                                    انتخاب کنید</label>

                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit">
                                    آپلود
                                </button>
                            </div>

                            <br>
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar bg-success" id="progress-bar" style="width: 2%">0%</div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


    </div>
   </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.2.2/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#uploadForm').submit(function (e) {
            if ($('#userImage').val()) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                    target: '#targetLayer',
                    beforeSubmit: function () {
                        $("#progress-bar").width('0%');
                    },
                    uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                        $("#progress-bar").width(percentComplete + '%');
                        $("#progress-bar").html('<div id="progress-status">' + percentComplete + ' %</div>')
                    },
                    success: function () {

                    },
                    resetForm: true
                });
                // return false;
            }
        });
    });
   </script>

    <script type="application/javascript">
    $('input[type="file"]').change(function (e) {
        var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
        $('.custom-file-label').html(fileName);
    });
    </script>

     <!--   Core JS Files   -->
      <script src="assets/js/core/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="assets/js/core/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="assets/js/core/bootstrap-material-design.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
     <!--  Google Maps Plugin    -->
     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE"></script>
     <!-- Chartist JS -->
     <script src="assets/js/plugins/chartist.min.js"></script>
     <!--  Notifications Plugin    -->
     <script src="assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>
     <!-- Control Center for Material Dashboard: parallax effects, scripts for the example pages etc -->
      <script src="assets/js/material-dashboard.min.js?v=2.1.0" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <!-- Material Dashboard DEMO methods, don't include it in your project! -->
     <script src="assets/demo/demo.js"></script>
        <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Javascript method's body can be found in assets/js/demos.js
        md.initDashboardPageCharts();

    });
     </script>
       </body>

     </html>
```

uploadajax file for upload

```
    <?php
if(!empty($_FILES)) {
    $dir_base = "uploadvideo/";
    //filter extentions
    $fileExt = explode('.', $_FILES['userImage']['name']);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
    $allowed = array('gif','jpg','png','svg');
    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'],$dir_base.$_FILES['userImage']['name'])) {
                // return path
                echo '<img src="'.$dir_base.$_FILES['userImage']['name'].'" width="100%"  />';
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo '<span style="color:red">You cannot upload files of this type!</span>';

    }
}
?>
```

how to can resolve this problem form for work and upload file?

Comment: I tested and it's work https://jsfiddle.net/gabriel81mi/36d59xva/ I see in your code there are 2 jquery, remove the second one. If is still not work, remove script by script and test until you will not find which one do the problem

Comment: @GabrieleCarbonai thanks a lot,i removed and fixed